# 権限が無くてもロールバックしたい

Tags: 機能の要求, 編集

ロールバックという機能があります。編集される前の状態に戻す機能です。例えば…

```
質問を投稿(リビジョン1)
   ↓
編集(リビジョン2)
   ↓
ロールバック(1になる)
```

---

しかしこの機能、編集の権限が無いと使えないのです。(自分の質問だったら使える)
これは少し不便だと思います。編集だとピアレビューに回されます。ロールバックも同じようにピアレビューに回せばいいのではないでしょうか。
権限が無くてもロールバックできるようにしていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 個人的にロールバックを権限なくても出来るようになったら、質問者・回答者を編集されたら、自分でロールバックします。もしこの機能を適用したら、自分の投稿に他のユーザーの編集をロールバックできないとかの制限を付ける必要があります。（当サイトのユーザーは非常にいいですが、この変更点は全てのサイトに適用されるので、最悪の場合も想像する必要があります）